# Where does the \setarrowlabelsep argument go within the scheme environment in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I tried looking in the documentation, but I can't seem to find the exact position for the `\setarrowlabelsep` in the `\schemestart` environment of the `chemfig` package. I would like the label Gpx shifted closer to the curved downwards arrow and the label GR closer to the curved upwards arrow. Any help or hint in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\makeatletter
\definearrow4{s>}{%
\ifx\@empty#3\@empty
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF@full]\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
\else
\def\curvedarrow@style{shorten <=\CF@arrow@offset,shorten >=\CF@arrow@offset,}%
\CF@expadd@tocs\curvedarrow@style\CF@arrow@current@style
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\curvedarrow@style,-CF@full(\CF@arrow@start@name)..controls#3..(\CF@arrow@end@name);
\CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}{+}{\CF@arrow@start@name}{#2}{0.5}{-}{\CF@arrow@end@name}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
\textsc{l}-Glutamate\arrow(c1--c2){->}[-90]\parbox{2cm}\centering$\upgamma$\hyp{}Glutamyl\hyp{}cysteine}
\arrow(--c3){->}[-90]\chemfig{GSH}
\arrow(--c4){0}[-90]\chemfig{GSSG}
\arrow(@c3.180--@c4.180){s>[][*{0.base east}Gpx][+(180:1.5)and+(180:1.5)]}[-90]
\arrow(@c4.0--@c3.0){s>[][*{0.base west}GR][+(0:1.5)and+(0:1.5)]}[90]
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is missing an opening brace for the `\parbox` and a `\fi` in the arrow definition. After adding those I changed the definition of the arrow as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\definearrow4{s>}{%
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF@full]
      \CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
  \else
    \def\curvedarrow@style{shorten <=\CF@arrow@offset,shorten >=\CF@arrow@offset,}%
    \CF@expadd@tocs\curvedarrow@style\CF@arrow@current@style
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\curvedarrow@style,-CF@full]
    (\CF@arrow@start@name)..controls#3..(\CF@arrow@end@name);
    % here would be a better position for the \fi
    %
    % this will allow to shift the label nodes
    % (argument #4 wasn't used, anyway) ...
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#4}%
    % ... if you use the \CF@arrow@...@node rather than
    % \CF@arrow@...@name:
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}{+}{\CF@arrow@start@node}{#2}{0.5}{+}{\CF@arrow@end@node}
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This defines an arrow type `s>` that has four optional arguments:

```
\arrow{s>[ label ][ label ][ specs for the curve ][ label offset ]}
```

which produces a straight arrow when the third option is empty (but also won't display the labels then, since they are placed in the `\else` branch; you might want to change that). If the third argument is specified a curved arrow is drawn. This requires the third argument to be a correct specification for the TikZ `.. controls ..` syntax: `.. controls <here goes the third argument> ..`.

With the above definition we get:

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\makeatletter
\definearrow4{s>}{%
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF@full]
      \CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node);%
  \else
    \def\curvedarrow@style{shorten <=\CF@arrow@offset,shorten >=\CF@arrow@offset,}%
    \CF@expadd@tocs\curvedarrow@style\CF@arrow@current@style
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\curvedarrow@style,-CF@full]
    (\CF@arrow@start@name)..controls#3..(\CF@arrow@end@name);
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#4}%
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}{+}{\CF@arrow@start@node}{#2}{0.5}{+}{\CF@arrow@end@node}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% \schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
  \textsc{l}-Glutamate
  \arrow(c1--c2){->}[-90]
  \parbox{2cm}{\centering$\upgamma$\hyp{}Glutamyl\hyp{}cysteine}
  \arrow(--c3){->}[-90]
  \chemfig{GSH}
  \arrow(--c4){0}[-90]
  \chemfig{GSSG}
  \arrow(@c3.180--@c4.180){s>[][*{0.base east}Gpx][+(180:1.5)and+(180:1.5)]}[-90]
  \arrow(@c4.0--@c3.0){s>[][*{0.base west}GR][+(0:1.5)and+(0:1.5)][5pt]}[90]
\schemestop

\end{document}
```